# KafkaStreams Scala grouping on 2 fields to get distinct count

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, count, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following Key-Value data in my Kafka topic

```
0 -> {"UserId":"123","DateAndTime":"2020-06-10T10:30:03.000Z"}
0 -> {"UserId":"123","DateAndTime":"2020-05-10T10:30:03.000Z"}
1 -> {"UserId":"234","DateAndTime":"2020-06-10T10:30:03.000Z"}
1 -> {"UserId":"235","DateAndTime":"2020-06-10T10:33:03.000Z"}
```

How do I get the count of users per key whose DateAndTime is in today's date interval using Kafka Streams in Scala?

Output should be like

```
Key -> Count of Users
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs and examples:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#
- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/main/scala/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountScalaExample.scala

You basically apply a `KStream#groupByKey()#windowedBy(TimeWindow.of(Duration.ofDay(1)))#count()`